# PDO Fetch data returns array of string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get data from a MySQL database with `PDO` but unfortunately `PDO` returns the result as an array of strings. I want to keep the native MySQL data types in the result array.

I have tried setting `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` to both `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` AND `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` but it was still returning `INT` data as string.

Here is the result of dump:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[27]
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'avatar' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'fullName' => string 'Mikheil Janiashvili' (length=19)
      public 'email' => string 'xxxxx@yyyyy.com' (length=17)
      public 'phone' => string '23 3537 20 03544' (length=12)
      public 'educationGE' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'educationEN' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'educationRU' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'experienceGE' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'experienceEN' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'experienceRU' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'descriptionGE' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'descriptionEN' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'descriptionRU' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: There are a couple of things that may affect this. One, emulated prepares I _think_ might cause this, so turn that off, the second is that it really depends on the PDO drivers being used. Since you don't say what DBMS you're using, nor what version of the lib / driver is being used (see phpinfo) there's not much else to say.

Comment: I am using php 5.5.12  disabled emulated prepares and everything is fine now.

Comment: yeah but  i needed proper data types for angular object

Comment: @miken32 thanks for showing good example it will help other people to find answer faster,  that's the exact solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you instantiate your PDO object, you need to tell it to use MySQL's native prepared queries:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Assuming you're using PHP >= 5.3 you will be using the mysqlnd library, which can return proper data types from prepared queries.

Example:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $db = PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "test", "");
php > $res = $db->query("SELECT 1 as num, PI()");
php > var_dump($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
array(2) {
  ["num"] => string(1) "1"
  ["PI()"] => string(8) "3.141593"
}

php > $db = PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "test", "", [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false]);
php > $res = $db->query("SELECT 1 as num, PI()");
php > var_dump($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
array(2) {
  ["num"] => int(1)
  ["PI()"] => float(3.141593)
}
php >
```